# how to divide this into class and object Loginform.py and Registrationform.py

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

heres the starting code of the gui.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image  # type "Pip install pillow" in your terminal to install ImageTk and Image module
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox, Tk


window = Tk()
window.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
window.state('zoomed')
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.title('Login and Registration Page')

    # Window Icon Photo
icon = PhotoImage(file='images\\pic-icon.png')
window.iconphoto(True, icon)

LoginPage = Frame(window)
RegistrationPage = Frame(window)

for frame in (LoginPage, RegistrationPage):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')


def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

show_frame(LoginPage)
```

how can i make this page into different file by using class so that the code wont be any long and clean. i cant post the whole code since it said it will be all code so i just need help with this one need to make this a object oriented code

```
# ==================== LOGIN PAGE =====================================================================================


design_frame1 = Listbox(LoginPage, bg='#0c71b9', width=250, height=100, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0)
design_frame1.place(x=0, y=0)

# ====== Email ====================
email_entry = Entry(design_frame4, fg="#a7a7a7", font=("yu gothic ui semibold", 12), highlightthickness=2,
                    textvariable=Email)

# function for show and hide password
def password_command():
    if password_entry1.cget('show') == '•':
        password_entry1.config(show='')
    else:
        password_entry1.config(show='•')
```

Comment: can email me for the whole code really need some help.

Comment: no, nobody will "email" you "for the whole code". please take the [tour], review [ask] and [mre] and [help/on-topic]

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing unique to tkinter in this question. Just using the basic rules of python, put the class in a file, then import the class into another file.

For example, create a file named `LoginForm.py`. In it put a class that has the log in form. This class should inherit from tkinter's `Frame` class so it can be added to other windows.

It might look something like this:

```
# login_form.py
class LoginPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        ...
        self.password_entry1 = tk.Entry(self)
        ...

    # function for show and hide password
    def password_command(self):
        if self.password_entry1.cget('show') == '•':
            password_entry1.config(show='')
        else:
            password_entry1.config(show='•')
    ...
```

Then, import this into your main file and use `LoginPage` just like any other widget.

```
from login_form import LoginPage
...
for frame in (LoginPage, ...):
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
```

Comment: should i also create a class from the mainpage?

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'LoginPage' from partially initialized module 'UploadingPic' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\User

Comment: @cj_123: make sure that `login_form` doesn't import your main file.

Comment: the best course of action is to recommend teaching material and a forum supporting beginners that are just learning python.